# Flexbox inside list group in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to list transactions in a list group component, but I want to present it the following way:

- Colored icon on the left
- Text "column" with description, and subtext under
- Sum and subtext right aligned

See the following example:

[image]

I want to solve this using list group and flexbox, but I do not have alot of experience with flexbox :(

Current code:

```css
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <i class="mdi mdi-help-circle-outline" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-between">
            <span>KLARNA AB</span>
            <span>-99</span>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <small class="t-category text-muted">
                Brukskonto &middot; Category
            </small>
            <small class="text-muted">Thu Feb 28</small>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far ? There is a lot of skeleton example on the web like this one https://codepen.io/oslego/pen/XdvWmd

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, the image is just a wireframe, that should represent text and image, not an "actual wireframe" or "fill space".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```css
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
                    <div class="mr-4">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-help-circle-outline h2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex-grow-1">
                        {{ $transaction->description }}<br /> 
                        <small class="text-muted">
                            {{ $transaction->account->name }} &middot; Category
                        </small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-column text-right">
                        {{ $transaction->amount }}<br />
                        <small class="text-muted">
                            {{ $transaction->date->format('D M j') }}
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </a>
```